# format_date() not working

Tags: datetime

I've got a field in a content type called "field_program_date" of type "Date". I'm using Drupal's `format_date()` function to format the date in the content template like this:

```
$program_date = format_date($node->field_program_date[$node->language][0]['value'], 'custom', 'F j, Y');
print $program_date;
```

Something is wrong because nothing gets printed out at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the date is not coming out as a timestamp, you can to use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Something like:

```
$date = strtotime($node->field_program_date[$node->language][0]['value']);
$program_date = format_date($date, 'custom', 'F j, Y');
print $program_date;
```

Comment: Yep! That did it! For correctness, and if anyone is cutting and pasting this, it looks like there's a missing semicolon at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing out the value of $node->field_program_date[$node->language][0]['value']? [format_date](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7) takes a unix timestamp as it's first param. So if the variable isn't in a format like "1429026611," then you'll need to convert it to a timestamp first.

Comment: That's got to be it! It prints out like this: `2015-04-10 00:00:00`. How do I convert it into a timestamp?

Comment: Use php's strtotime function. For readability, you might want to set a var as the unix timstamp, and just send the var in the format_date function call.